# Error opening bucket #bucket: failed to connect to any of the specified hosts(Sync gateway auth to Couchbase using x.509 certificate.)

Tags: couchbase, x509, couchbase-sync-gateway

This is the sync-gateway-config.json file that I am using to authenticate:

```
**sync-gateway-config.json** file
{
“interface”:":4984",
“logging”: {
“log_file_path”: “C:/Program Files/Couchbase/Sync Gateway/var/lib/couchbase/logs/sg_logs”,
“console”: {
“enabled”: true,
“log_level”: “info”,
“log_keys”: [
“*”
]
}
},
“databases”:{
“db”:{
“use_views”: true,
“cacertpath”: “C:/Program Files/servercertfiles/ca.pem”,
“certpath”: “C:/Program Files/servercertfiles/clientcertfiles/seedata.pem”,
“keypath”: “C:/Program Files/servercertfiles/clientcertfiles/seedata.key”,
“server”: “couchbases://127.0.0.1”,
“bucket”: “bucketname”,
“username”: “sync_gateway”
}
}

}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
[INF] GoCBCustomSGTranscoder Opening Couchbase database bucketname on couchbases://127.0.0.1 as user “sync_gateway”
2020-07-13T15:38:20.566+05:30 [INF] Error opening bucket bucketname: failed to connect to any of the specified hosts

Links followed :*https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/2.7/security.html#x-509-certificates*
```

Comment: What is it that you think this config is doing?  Because to me the error is pretty clear:  Sync Gateway is unable to connect to the couchbase server runnning at 127.0.01